# If I already mention "there is a chance", can I still say in the same sentence "chances are"?

Tags: grammaticality, redundancy

If I already mention “there is a chance”, can I still say in the same sentence “chances are”?

> Now of course, there is a chance you will ignore the poster, but chances are (most of the time) you will wonder why the poster only has one letter on it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I put into the right parenthesis. I use parethese because I'm not sure if that phrase is needed.

Comment: No, the part in parentheses is not needed, unless you want to stress or clarify that the case is "most of the time". And yes, you can use chances twice like this. This does not cause a grammatical issue. There might be some logical confusion, or an issue regarding style. But those are matters of opinion, not grammaticality.

Comment: @Max Or the repetiion _itself_ can be stylish: _There is a chance you will ignore the poster, but chances are you won't._

Comment: Why would you think you might not be able to do this? Does it break some rule of grammar of something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you may say both in the same sentence.

The phrase

> chances are

means there is a high probability *something* will happen, however, the outcome is not certain, therefore

> there is a chance

it may not happen.

You can use the conjunction "but" for opposing outcomes, or "and" for joint outcomes.

> There is a chance it will rain today, but chances are it will be sunny.
>   There is a chance it will rain today, and chances are it will be humid.

Comment: Does "chances are" mean likely?

Comment: Yes, that there is a higher probability of *something* happening than not. "Chances are this will happen and chances are that will not happen."